# XML Parser Android - Calling New Activity

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-activity

I have a question about xml parser in android. I am creating button information in the xml. I am getting its height,width,color and so on. I am creating all buttons in a function. Now i want to do the following. When i click the buttons, new android page opens. As far as i know i will do it by creating new activities.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                      startActivity(i);

                }
            });
```

I am writing this on my function which i create all buttons.when i do this it does not work.can somebody help me?

Comment: It does not work how ? It does nothing or the application crashes ? If so, may you post the error it gives you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **Activity** :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_main);

        View btnTapOnMe = findViewById(R.id.btnTapOnMe);
        btnTapOnMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

**view_main.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTapOnMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tap on Me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.yourpackage"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name="com.yourpackage.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.yourpackage.MainActivity2"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Should work like a charm

**UPDATE:**

Don't ever use `AbsoluteLayout` [it is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html)

> This class was deprecated in API level 3.
>   Use FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or a custom layout instead.

First of all change it to Frame or Relative layout.

Here what i get in my example below :
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public void AddAllButtons() {
        AbsoluteLayout Layout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Test case");
        Layout.addView(btn);
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();
        absParams.x = 100;
        absParams.y = 100;
        absParams.width = 150;
        btn.setLayoutParams(absParams);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_main);


        AddAllButtons();
    }
}
```

and here is xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTapOnMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tap on Me"/>

    <AbsoluteLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTapOnMe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I edited the manifest.xml but i am loading the data from an xml file

Comment: What data are you loading? Can you make your question more clear? What can not you do? Maybe you can show us full sources of activity and that `xml` file

Comment: I am loading button info from xml and there ara multiple buttons when clicking each button i need different activities.

Comment: i am creating this buttons in a function

Comment: inside the function i am writing this:          btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                   startActivity(i);

       }
      });

Comment: In my example I'm also loading button from `xml`, and starting new `Activity` on click on it

Comment: I know that it will work but inside of my function i does not work, i did not understand why

Comment: Try to create all files like I did in example and if it will work with one button you can then add as many as you need

Comment: Then please show me all your `Activity` code. I can't tell you what is wrong other way

Comment: Just edit your question and add your Activity code there

Comment: I have another question can you please help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175603/android-xml-parser-creating-spinner